# CRM Dynamics 2011 import: no data

Tags: import, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, no-data

I try to migrate data from an online CRM trial environment to an on premise CRM installation both version 2011. I first migrated the solution. Now I want to migrate the data of my custom entities. In the export I include the column headers to facilitate the import into the on premise CRM instance. I try to do this through the import wizard. Everything goes fine: in the system tasks overview I can see that the files content gets parsed, transformed and imported but no data is actually imported although the import xml files contain data.
Any ideas how to solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you can only use the export with column headers when you plan to import into the same CRM instance again. If you export with column headers the primary key of the table is exported along which makes it unusable for import on other CRM instances

Answer (score 1):

When you open imported crm file from list, is there any records in list of 'Fully imported' entities? I suppose, like you sad that importing has 'Completed' status.
If there are records here, try to change view on your list of entities. (All something)

[image]

Edit:

Try [this tutorial](http://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/crm-2011-importingexporting-data-between-organisations/) for export/import crm data. Pay attention to this note:

> Do not check make this data available for reimport checkbox as this
>   feature is meant to export and update data in the same organization
>   and not for cross organization data migration.

Comment: Hi, I try to import the standard xml file as exported from the online CRM instance, so only one worksheet. When I check the CRM DB, I can see that the concerning table is empty: no records.

Comment: When you click on 'Export data' you don't have to check option 'Make this data available for reimport...'. Just select 'static worksheet with records from this page' and click on Export. After saving file on disk you can convert it to CSV and then try reimport. Thats work for me.

Answer (score 0):

What type of file are you trying to import?

In my experience using the 2003 xml workbook format that is available in excel works best.

Let me know if you get better results. Also make sure that you have only 1 worksheet!!

Comment: Seems Like Wolovin finds it important to add spaces

Comment: Hi, I try to import the standard xml file as exported from the online CRM instance, so only one worksheet.